# How set (hashset) in python works, especially in comparison?

Tags: python-3.x, set, hashtable, hashset

I am learning hash table and BST. I got confused when I compared (True) with True I have got True as an answer. But if I compare (True, True) == True, True I,m getting set: (False, True). Why it is happening so?
[image: here is my code]

Comment: Note that there are no sets or "hashsets" involved here at all. You should also post text as text, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The equality expression is comparing the tuple on the left hand side with the first instance of `True` only.  It looks like there should be pair-wise comparisons, but that is not happening.  The last line here is how python interpreter sees this expression, which is:

- the comparison of a tuple to a **single** value
- the integer 123
- the string "Dog"

---

```
>>> (True, True) == True, True
(False, True)
>>> (True, True) == True, 123, 'Dog'
(False, 123, 'Dog')
>>> ((True, True) == True), 123, 'Dog'
(False, 123, 'Dog')
```